# Making UI communicate with logic

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have begun playing around with Shoes.rb and I have an hard time making the UI working with some logics. For instance I'd like to send a message to an object when a button is clicked so I have the following code:

```
    Shoes.app do
      button "Run" do
        @label.replace Calculator.add(1,1)
      end
      @label = para "Result will show up here"
   end
```

I have also my Calculator class

```
class Calculator
  def self.add(x,y)
    x+y
  end
end
```

How can I make it work?
I have tried to add the class under the Shoes block (adding also it into a module) and having the class in a separate required file but nothing works.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `Calculator` definition before the `Shoes.app` block:

```
class Calculator
  def self.add(x,y)
    x+y
  end
end

Shoes.app do
  button "Run" do
    @label.replace Calculator.add(1,1)
  end
  @label = para "Result will show up here"
end
```

Otherwise, code in the `Shoes.app` block can't access the `Calculator` class.

[image: before click]

[image: after click]

Comment: Thanks, actually I was able also to require external file, I had a typo before.